# Jackson create JavaType from Class

Tags: java, class, jackson, jackson2

There must be a way to create a `JavaType` from `String.class`?

Note: The input for the method **must be** `JavaType` for my use case because that value is created dynamically using `TypeFactory`.

```java
/** Returns a JavaType for Map<String, valueType> **/
private static JavaType stringToJavaType(JavaType valueType) {
    TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
    // this does not compile, can't mix Class and JavaType
    return typeFactory.constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, valueType);
}
```

If I may tack on a related question, what is the advantage of `constructMapType` over `constructParametricType`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it by:

- [constructFromCanonical](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructFromCanonical-java.lang.String-) method. For example: `typeFactory.constructFromCanonical(String.class.getName())`
- [constructType](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructType-java.lang.reflect.Type-) method. For example: `typeFactory.constructType(new TypeReference<String>() {})`.
- [constructArrayType](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructArrayType-java.lang.Class-) method. For example: `typeFactory.constructArrayType(String.class).getContentType()`. But it looks a little bit like a workaround.
- [<del>SimpleType.constructUnsafe</del>](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/SimpleType.html#constructUnsafe-java.lang.Class-) method. For example: `SimpleType.constructUnsafe(String.class)`. Note from documentation: *Method used by core Jackson classes: NOT to be used by application code: it does NOT properly handle inspection of super-types, so neither parent Classes nor implemented Interfaces are accessible with resulting type instance.* So, even it is possible to use try to avoid it.

Answer (score 13):

If you are here just because you want to create a `JavaType` from a `Class` object,
then use an `ObjectMapper` like so:

```
   JavaType javaType = objectMapper.constructType(clazz);
```

Comment: Yeah. Hmm. Didn't realize `Class` is `Type`.