# How to deserialize generic List<T> with Jackson?

Tags: java, list, class, jackson, type-erasure

I've been using Jackson to serialize/deserialize objects for years and have always found it needlessly complicated to use `TypeReference<T>` to deserialize `List` etc. I created a simple helper function:

```
public static <T> TypeReference<List<T>> list() {
    return new TypeReference<List<T>>(){}
}
```

With intended use:

```
List<Foo> foos = objectMapper.readValue(json, list());
```

And it works! Kind of. When inspecting through the debugger, rather than a list of `Foo`, it is rather a list of `LinkedHashMap`. I understand that `ObjectMapper` deserializes into `LinkedHashMap` for type `Object` and I read the explanation for that here:

[Jackson and generic type reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846244/jackson-and-generic-type-reference)

However, why is it able to assign `List<LinkedHasMap>` to a `List<Foo>`? At the very least shouldn't that be some sort of `ClassCastException`?

Also, is there anyway to do this with Java's type system?

NOTE: the following method declaration has the same issue, which makes sense because the additional argument is not needed for `T` to be determined:

```
public static <T> TypeReference<List<T>> listOf(Class<T> ignored) {
    return new TypeReference<List<T>>(){}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson and generic type reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846244/jackson-and-generic-type-reference)

Comment: Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578452/how-to-use-jacksons-typereference-with-generics

Comment: There's no difference between a `List<LinkedHasMap>` and a `List<Foo>` at runtime, because of type erasure.

Comment: See also [Gson deserialize list and class, how does erasure work here?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61134913/5221149) Different library, exact same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works like this because of **type erasure** in Java. Please, read about it before you start reading next part of this answer:

- [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)
- [Type Erasure in Java Explained](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)
- [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

As you probably know right now, after reading above articles, your method after compilation looks like this:

```
static <T> TypeReference<List> listOf(Class<T> ignored) {
    return new TypeReference<List>(){};
}
```

Jackson will try to find out the most appropriate type for it which will be `java.util.LinkedHashMap` for a JSON object. To create an *irrefutable* type, you need to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory` class. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonTypeApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println("Try with 'TypeFactory'");
        List<Id> ids = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, CollectionsTypeFactory.listOf(Id.class));
        System.out.println(ids);
        Id id1 = ids.get(0);
        System.out.println(id1);

        System.out.println("Try with 'TypeReference<List<T>>'");
        List<Id> maps = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, CollectionsTypeFactory.erasedListOf(Id.class));
        System.out.println(maps);
        Id maps1 = maps.get(0);
        System.out.println(maps1);
    }
}

class CollectionsTypeFactory {
    static JavaType listOf(Class clazz) {
        return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, clazz);
    }

    static <T> TypeReference<List> erasedListOf(Class<T> ignored) {
        return new TypeReference<List>(){};
    }
}

class Id {
    private int id;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above example, for below `JSON` payload:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 22
  },
  {
    "id": 333
  }
]
```

prints:

```
Try with 'TypeFactory'
[{1}, {22}, {333}]
{1}
Try with 'TypeReference<List<T>>'
[{id=1}, {id=22}, {id=333}]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.example.Id
    at com.example.JsonTypeApp.main(JsonTypeApp.java:27)
```

See also:

- [How to use Jackson's TypeReference with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578452/how-to-use-jacksons-typereference-with-generics)
- [Jackson create JavaType from Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850439/jackson-create-javatype-from-class)

Comment: You saved my day. Can I ask you how do you come to this solution?

Comment: @MarcoSulla, I use `Jackson` for a long time. And I have read a lot of articles about it for last few years. You can take a look on my other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A51591+%5Bjackson%5D)