# Convert JSON array to object using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a JSON array of array, like below:

```json
[ 
    [1,2,"str"],
    [1,2,"str"],
    [1,2,"str"],
]
```

I want to convert this JSON to an array of objects. Actually I want each inner array to represent an object with the following class. Therefore the result is an array of `MyType` (Note that my class `MyType` has a constructor corresponding to the mentioned inner array):

```java
class MyType {
 int x;
 int y;
 String text;
 
 public MyType(int x, int y, String text){
   this.x=x;
   this.y=y;
   this.text=text;
 }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)` annotation for class with `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` for constructor. You can deserialise it to an array `mapper.readValue(jsonFile, MyType[].class)` or `mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<List<MyType>>(){})` . See also [How to deserialize generic List<T> with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150873/how-to-deserialize-generic-listt-with-jackson/61154659#61154659)