# Deserialization to a list of undefined generic type

Tags: java, json, jackson

I defined a class Person:

```java
public static class Person{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    // Getters, setters, contructor...
}
```

I run the following code:

```java
@Test
public void minimalGenericJackson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(23);
    list.add(new Person("John", "Doe"));

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);


    final List outList = objectMapper.readValue(json, List.class);
    final Person person = (Person) outList.get(1);
}
```

The Json string must be serialized and then back deserialized into a java object. In the end of the deserialization process I need the Person item to be deserialized as Object of a Person type, but in my case that is not it, it is deserialized into a LinkedHashMap. If possible, I would need a sloution that does not change the test code, only the Person.java code.

The code I run produces the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be
> cast to class
> de.mpg.ipp.codac.archivedb.restapi.JsonTestsPlayground$Person
> (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> de.mpg.ipp.codac.archivedb.restapi.JsonTestsPlayground$Person is in
> unnamed module of loader 'app')

Is it possible to solve this issue only by adding Jackson annotations to the Person class. Maybe by defining Person class to get attached type property. Like it is done using `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`, but I didn't manage to use these in my case as person is not a subtype of another class of mine. Also I would like to avoid enabling default typing.

The List should have undefined generic type as it may contain any primitive value, and/or the Person object. The goal of my problem is to successfully deserialize List containing a Person object and other primitive values.

`TypeReference` and `JavaType` can not be used in this case as the List contains values of variable primitive types and Person objects.

Comment: You need to pass the appropriate type to `readValue`. `List.class` is not sufficient. See [Jackson and generic type reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846244/jackson-and-generic-type-reference) and [How to deserialize generic List<T> with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150873/how-to-deserialize-generic-listt-with-jackson)

Comment: The list should have undefined generic type as it may contain any primitive value, and/or the Person object. This is one of the requirements. Will add to description

Comment: You can't have an undefined type, because then Jackson can't select a type and will use a `LinkedHashMap`. The only option I am aware of would be to have a common interface and use type info to describe the appropriate types (but maybe there are more advanced tricks).

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you can't cast HashMap to your custom Object, so if you want to have a generic list, you must convert every time the HashMap to your custom object.

ES.

```
public static class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    // Getters, setters, constructor...
}
```

You can run the following code and it will work:

```
@Test
public void minimalGenericJackson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(23);
        list.add(new Person("John", "Doe"));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final List<Object> outList = objectMapper.convertValue(list, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(outList));

        final Person person = objectMapper.convertValue(outList.get(1), Person.class);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(person));
}
```

Comment: The main challenge is to provide annotations to Person class or othere mapper features that will make it possible for the deserialization to produce Person object of type Person and not of type LinkedHashMap

Comment: i think you can't do that...